# Looking for a movie I saw as a child: boy went back in time, friend died, later born again

Tags: story-identification, suspended-animation

The movie was about a boy who went back in time to a pirate era and met a friend there who later in the movie died. The boy never was able to return to his time but was able to witness his friend be born again in later time.

Comment: To a **what** era? I guess "irate" was a typo, but what was it meant to be?

Comment: when were you a child? was it live action? was it in english? was it geared towards any age group? was the boy a small child, or a teen? can you describe him? did it seem to be a made for tv movie? did you see it in a theater or on tv?

Comment: was the character ever actually put into suspended animation (as you tagged the question), or was there just time travel?

Comment: @user14111 Probably pirate?

Comment: @randal'thor Duh. Hey, I just got up. Need coffee.

Comment: @user14111 Methinks I spot an Australian... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised I found this. Is the movie "The Boy and the Pirates" made in 1960? Several synopsis links to look at:  [here](http://www.thepirateking.com/movies/) (scroll down 14 entries), [here](http://www.tcm.com/tcmdb/title/17458/The-Boy-and-the-Pirates/full-synopsis.html), and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Boy_and_the_Pirates)

[image]

I never saw this movie myself.  However the plot summaries available especially on thepirateking.com and tcm.com lead me to believe this might be it, given the boy does go back in time to Blackbeard's ship (via a genie's magic).  It was re-released on DVD after the success of the first "Pirates of the Caribbean" movie.

The "died and later re-born" part of the plot threw me some, until I saw that the same child actress played the part of the boy's friend in his present day (Kathy), and of his new friend in the past (Katrina).  The past version of his friend (Katrina) did not explicitly die, but rather faded away, so perhaps your younger self thought that she died and that Katrina was later resurrected as Kathy.

But the "never was able to return to his time" is not a part of this movie (the boy does make it back to his present). And the "able to witness his friend be born" part is not literally in this movie (that would be quite a "no-no" for a 1960's family movie).  And certainly the "suspended-animation" tag you chose for the question does not play a part in this movie.

So if those parts of your memory of the movie are solid, then perhaps this is not the movie you are looking for.